# jQuery Remove same Class on Multiple Id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to remove the same class on multiple ids

Here's the code:

```
var test = ['#step-1','#step-2','#step-3'];

$(test).removeClass('active-step');
```

This is not working, my question is..what's the problem or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: $('[id^=step]').removeClass("active-step");

Comment: Shouldn't it just be one string? $('#step-1,#step-2,#step-3')....

Comment: Jquery selector acts the same as CSS selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the classes of all elements whose id starts with step, then you can use starts `^` with attribute selector

```
$("[id^='step']").removeClass('active-step');
```

I thing your requirement is to remove the active calsses and add the active class to a particular element, then you can use like this too,

```
$(".active-step").removeClass('active-step');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to frame that array as a [`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/),

```
var test = ['#step-1','#step-2','#step-3'];
$(test.join()).removeClass('active-step');
```

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), `.join()` will merge the elements of an array by using comma(`,`) if none supplied as its delimitter. So in our case, this signature would be useful in making a multiple selector.

> separator : Optional. Specifies a string to separate each element of
>   the array. The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If
>   omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma. If separator
>   is an empty string, all elements are joined without any characters in
>   between them.

Comment: This seems like the best answer to me. The id could start with anything and this accounts for that.

Comment: $(test.join()), this part is actually doing the same thing like
$('#step-1, #step-2, #step-3')

Comment: comma delimited worked better for my use case, but .join is great if the list is dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct jQuery syntax to select multiple ids:

`$('#step-1, #step-2, #step-3').removeClass('active-step');`